# htaccess gives a new url but browser display error 404-not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here is structure:

```
public_html
    .htaccess
    folder
        art.php
    folder
        art.php
```

ugly url - example.com/folder/art.php?id=9&s=lorem-ipsum
pretty url - example.com/folder/9/lorem-ipsum

pretty url is there - but getting error 404 - not found

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\s&]*)/art\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ art.php?id=$1&s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**art.php**

```
<base href = 'https://example.com'>
```

pls help

Comment: Try using a full path `/folder/art.php?id=$1&s=$1` in the rule's substitution

Comment: `RewriteRule ^folder/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /folder/art.php?id=$1&s=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @AmitVerma - it works, thanks a lot. Does it mean I need to write the same for each folder? There are plenty of them. Each of them is a string, maybe there is a simple solution